# go template (helm, kubernetes)

Tags: kubernetes

```
values.yaml
aa:
  bb:
    cc:
      dd: "hi~!!"
```

In the values ​​file above, the value "cc" is a variable.
I'm want to get "hi~!!".

```
myPod.yaml
apiVersion: v1
...
...
data:
  myData: {{ printf "%s\.dd" $variableKey | index .Values.aa.bb }}
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Have you tried? What was the results? You should mention the problems you facing while doing this.

Comment: There was an error and the helm chart did not run.  -> "%s\.dd"

Answer (score 1):

You need two separate args, `{{ index .Values.aa.bb $variableKey “dd” }}`